# Combining two SOQL queries into one

Tags: apex, soql

I have the following SOQL queries

```
Double counter1= [Select  count( )  from Opportunity where createdDate >=  Last_n_DAYS:30 and isClosed=true and Stagename!='Rejected'  ];
Double counter2= [Select  count( )  from Opportunity where createdDate >=  Last_n_DAYS:30 and isClosed=true and (StageName='Pending Payment' or Stagename ='Complete')];

System.debug((counter2 / counter1) *100);
```

Is it possible to combine them into 1,which would return the same result as `(counter2/counter1) *100` ?

NOTE: I can not use any intermediate variables, the end result has to come from a single query statement.

Comment: Select  count( )  from Opportunity where createdDate >=  Last_n_DAYS:30 and isClosed=true AND (Stagename!='Rejected' AND (StageName='Pending Payment' or Stagename ='Complete'))

Please test and verify

Comment: @CODEPirate your answer is the same as my counter2.  I want the end result to  be a percentage of counter2 out of coutnter1  and I am not sure how to achieve this in SOQL

Answer (score 6):

You could use an [aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm):

```
Integer counter1 = 0;
Integer counter2 = 0;
for (AggregateResult ar [
        select Stagename n, count() c
        from Opportunity
        where createdDate >= Last_n_DAYS:30
        and isClosed = true
        group by Stagename
        ]) {
    String n = (String) ar.get('n');
    Integer c = (Integer) at.get('c');
    if (n != 'Rejected') counter1 += c;
    if (n == 'Pending Payment' || n == 'Complete') counter2 += c;
}
System.debug((counter2 / counter1) * 100);
```

This returns a count for every `Stagename` and uses the Apex loop to sum those counts appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Keith C but  I am trying to use the result of the query in Geckoboard hence it will only allow me to write 1 single query that gives me the end result. Hence I would not be able to utilize any intermediate variable. However I do appreaciate your support

Comment: @MarcZaharescu Best add that constraint to the question... does that product have a forum where you can ask this question?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't , so I guess what I'm trying is not achievable in SOQL

Comment: Does geckoboard allow you to pull in data from a webservice call? You could write a webservice in SF using the logic that Keith has here and returning the single value.